# Inspect values in a structure in Poly/ML

Tags: sml, polyml

In Poly/ML, names of global values can be obtained by:

```
map #1 ((#allVal PolyML.globalNameSpace) ());
```

and top level strucutres can be obtained similarly using `#allStruct`.

Now, how can I list all values inside a structure?
That is, is there a way to implement `???` below?

```
> ??? "String";
["implode", "explode", "concatWith", ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my current workaround. 
You can delete all values from PolyML.globalNameSpace (forgetValue) then open the structure and repeat (#allVal PolyML.globalNameSpace) ()